# d3 dragging elements individually & by group

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have couple of rectangles inside a group, I want them to move in a group when the outer rectangle is dragged, But I should also be able to move the inner rectangles individually, I can do this separately, but I cannot make them work in same time. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agt84vof/). Can anyone help me on this?

```
<svg width="500" height="500" style="background-color: red">
    <g class="big">
        <rect class="sqr" height="200" width="400" x="40" y="40" style="fill:blue"></rect>
        <rect class="sqr" height="50" width="50" x="100" y="100" initial-x="100" initial-y="100" style="fill:green"></rect>
        <rect class="sqr" height="50" width="50" x="250" y="100" initial-x="100" initial-y="100" style="fill:green"></rect>
    </g>
</svg>



<script>

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', function(d){
        d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate('+(d3.event.x)+','+(d3.event.y)+')');
    });

    var sqDrag = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', function (d) {
        console.log('sqr dragging..');
        d3.select(this).attr('x', d3.mouse(this)[0]).attr('y',d3.mouse(this)[1]);
    });

    var g = d3.select('.big').call(drag);

    var r = d3.selectAll('.sqr').on('mousedown', function () {
        console.log('sqr clicked');
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
    }).call(sqDrag);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your sqDrag function

```
var sqDrag = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', function (d) {
    console.log('sqr dragging..');
    var id = d3.select(this).attr('id');
    if (id === null)
        d3.select(this).attr('x', d3.mouse(this)[0]).attr('y',d3.mouse(this)[1]);
    else {
        var parent = d3.select(this);
        var dx = d3.mouse(this)[0] - parent.attr('x');
        var dy = d3.mouse(this)[1] - parent.attr('y');

        parent.attr('x', d3.mouse(this)[0]).attr('y',d3.mouse(this)[1]);

        d3.selectAll("." + id).attr('x', function() {
            return Number(d3.select(this).attr('x')) + dx;
        }).attr('y', function() {
            return Number(d3.select(this).attr('y')) + dy;
        });
    }
});
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/46ag2x2z/